# How to remove these designs from my code ? (picture added)

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgODU.png)

I tried to eliminate it, but not able to do it and now its there on the entire code.

Comment: If you are talking about the whitespace characters and if you are using Eclipse, go to `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors` and click on the link `whitespace characters`

Comment: please mention which software you have used

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud Denoyelle :)